# Finding the roots of a function with a parameter

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I am using a differential equation method for finding the roots of a  function. My function is much more complicated but I can illustrate my problem with a trivial example. The problem occurs when roots coincide and change direction.
I use a differential equation method. The example equation is

```
eq = s^2 + 2 a s + 1;
```

where *a* is a parameter (0 < *a*) and I wish to find the roots as the parameter is varied.
To form the differential equation I take two derivatives and put them together as follows

```
deq = {D[eq, s], D[eq, a]} /. s -> s[a];
de = deq[[1]] s'[a] + deq[[2]] == 0
(* 2 s[a]+(2 a+2 s[a]) (s^\[Prime])[a]\[Equal]0 *)
```

I set up the differential equation so that I can solve with different initial conditions and over different ranges of the parameter *a*

```
ClearAll[sol];
sol[ic_, ae_] := s /. First[NDSolve[{de, s[0] == ic}, s, {a, 0, ae}]]
```

I have initial conditions from

```
ic = s /. Solve[eq == 0 /. a -> 0]
(* {-\[ImaginaryI],\[ImaginaryI]} *)
```

First case is fine

```
a1 = 0.999;
rts = sol[#, a1] & /@ ic;
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{Re[#[a]], Im[#[a]]} & /@ rts], {a, 0, 0.999}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Second case attempts to go further

```
a1 = 2;
rts = sol[#, a1] & /@ ic;
```

NDSolve gets stuck as it attempts to go "round the corner" at -1. Is there a way to get NDSolve to go round the corner? Can I get both solutions going round the corner and choosing opposite directions? (One solution should go towards the origin the other towards infinity.) Thanks for help and suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to draw a root locus -- there is a special command for this:

```
RootLocusPlot[s^2 + 2 a s + 1, {a, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.I am familiar with RootLocusPlot[] but my more complicated functions (not always a polynomial) needs a more "personal" touch. It is interesting to note that RootLocusPlot[] does get "round the corner". How does it do that?

Comment: Also, note that RootLocusPlot[] is the Evans Root Locus and assumes that there is a feedback path. If you look at your solution it does not go through the same points as mine.

Comment: You can apply the root locus to a simple polynomial rather than one with a feedback loop (there is an example in the docs). But in any case, it can only handle polynomials -- if you stick a Log or Exp or some nonlinearity, you would need to do it yourself.